# .NETCore image drawing libraries not working on linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, imagemagick.net

Hey guys I am trying to make an .NETCore app that draw some text on image and that is gonna be able to run on linux os.

I tried CoreCompat Drawing library, ImageSharp, ImageMagick and I couldnt get even one of them work on linux.

I develop the apps on Windows, everything works perfectly so I go and publish it for linux, I do a dotnet publish -r linux-arm, copy the publish folder onto my linux "server" and run it*(Same setup works for most of the .Netcore apps I did so far)*, but it throws almost the same exception for all of the libraries I tried, for example:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'NativeMagickSettings' threw an exception. --->
>   System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
>   'Magick.NET-Q8-x64.Native.dll': The specified module could not be
>   found.

That's with ImageMagick.Net for example. just replace the dll name and you got error for other libraries aswell.
And I am clueless I google some tips but noone of them worked. My question is if anyone has experience with this exception or if you know about some working image drawing library, please tell me its name :D

If I stay with imageMagick, I was working with this https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/Documentation/CrossPlatform.md

Package reference is correct, but it can't find any Magick.NET-Q8-x64.Native.dll.so

> ldd Magick.NET-Q8-x64.Native.dll.so

Also tried to:

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/ImageMagick/libraries

But without any results. So please if you have any clue what can I do or if you know about image library I can use on linux please say so, thanks :)

Comment: ImageSharp is a full NetStandard implementation. There are no dependency so it should work. I use it personally on linux without any issue

Comment: Is it supposed to work when you mix arm and x64 target platform ?

Comment: First try to run their samples, and then ping their developers. It is nor suitable to ask here (and such is off-topic).

Comment: switched to imageSharp and got it working